# France: involuntarily terminated, what happens to carte de séjour

Tags: france, residence-cards

I was hired by a French employer and sponsored to move to Paris in the spring. I was just involuntary terminated during my trial period, and my carte de séjour is being manufactured. What is my current legal status and how long do I have to stay in France to try to get a new job?

I was approved for a pluriannuelle under salarié qualifié / entreprise innovante, but it was sponsored by my employer. Does it remain tied to them? And should I expect it to be cancelled even as it is already in process? I was told I would be contacted by the préfecture once it was finished, but I haven’t heard back yet and was just let go this week.

Answer (score 1):

A residence permit or visa stays valid as long as it isn't rescinded. There is no obligation for you to leave the French territory immediately, that much is clear. At the same time, I don't really know how likely the *préfecture* is to move to rescind it and how fast. It could also be possible to stay for some time and look for another job as long as you are getting unemployment benefits but if you just moved to Paris, you might not have worked long enough to get any.

You also wrote that your *carte de séjour* is “being manufactured”. What's your basis for that? Applying for a permit is not a mere formality. Even if you already had to submit a lot of information to get a visa, legally your situation is being evaluated anew (I am assuming you are currently staying under the long-stay visa you needed to move to Paris). In my experience, it is rare to get any insights into what a decision might be ahead of the appointment to receive it. Until you have got your residence permit in hand, it could still be refused.

If the permit is refused, you would receive a letter informing you of this (or even be given that letter in person when you show up to your appointment at the *préfecture*) and it will probably come with what's called an *obligation de quitter le territoire français* (OQTF). From that point on, you have 30 days to leave (there are other variants like an OQTF *sans délai* but that's unlikely in your case).

It is not forbidden to change employers (i.e. you don't need to leave France to reapply) but your new employer will have to sponsor you again and you will have to submit a new application. That's more likely to work if you find a similar job (one that would qualify for a *passeport talent* on its own merits), you cannot take any job to make ends meet for now (that becomes possible after some time).

Comment: Hey! I received an Attestation de Decision Favorable for my pluriannuelle for four years, and it stated that « Ce document est actuellement en cours de fabrication. » Everything was already submitted and approved.

Comment: I was also told by my employer in writing today that I will still receive my « passeport talent », which I assume they mean as the carte de séjour, and that I will just need to get a new one completed by my employer « once I get a new job. » So it sounds like they have no intention of rescinding it, but just looking to understand the circumstances should I receive it at the préfecture. Thanks so much!

Comment: Typically employers have to notify Immigration when any kind of sponsored visa arrangement ends. What did your employer’s HR department say when you asked them how long the rules give you to find another job?

Comment: @Traveller What do you mean by “immigration“? In France, employers do not have to notify the *préfecture*. The *préfecture* could theoretically find out from URSSAF or the *inspection du travail* but as far as I know, they typically don't bother tracking this, instead counting on the fact that most permits have to be renewed once a year. Legally, they have the power to rescind a permit before its term, though.

Comment: @Relaxed In that case, by Immigration I meant the *préfecture*. The point I was really trying to make is that having hired and then fired a foreign worker, the OP’s *employer* surely ought to have a responsibility to a) know the full consequences of their decision and b) ensure the OP is fully informed of those consequences.